# Unable to connect database of lamp instance from servlet running on tomcat instance of google cloud

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, lamp, google-cloud-platform

I have two instances of my project running on Google's cloud, Tomcat Instance & Lamp Instance.

My servlets are running on tomcat instance and have to connect to the database of lamp instance.

I gave the following details of connection

```
String DriverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String userName="root";
String password="root";
String driverManager="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename";
```

The localhost request is going to mysql of tomcat instance(Here tomcat instance contains mysql also).It is not going to the lamp instance

So I want a way to send request to another instance.

if I placed lamp instance url means i am receiving the following exception in the logcat.

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

So can anyone tell how to solve this problem

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you connect to the lamp instance from your local machine? Are there firewalls in place? Is there a user with an appropriate host to match it? Are you listening to the network or a public IP? This question needs more info.

Comment: After creating lamp instance ,i got one ipaddress of this instance.I was able to connect through this ssh connection. I allowed both http and https traffic.is there anything extra we have to do for firewalls???If i place that external ip of lamp instance in that db url ,it is resulting in communication link failure..
I didn't understand the question.."is there an user with appropriate host to match it.?".Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the `Connector/J` by setting it to true, and also use the `google` `mysql` driver instead of the generic `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` class.

Enable connector/j

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  ...
  <use-google-connector-j>true</use-google-connector-j>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Google Driver class

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
```

[Code samples taken from URL.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/)

Comment: sir,i want to connect mysql database of lamp instance ,not cloud sql instance .. :/